# Using IPv6 with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, wcf

I would like to test PNRP in an IPv6 environment under virtualbox.

I have 2 XP VMs under virtualbox, and they only have IPv6 enabled.

Firstly can I enable DHCP for IPv6 under virtualbox. If not then how can I specify a manual IPv6 address within my XP VMs?

What I mean is that if I try to edit the IPv6 settings within the XP VMs I don't get the option to specify an IPv6 address. If I go 'Local Area Connection Properties -> Microsoft TCP/IP version 6' the properties button is disabled (which is how you would specify an IPv4 address when IPv4 is enabled).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to select "Attached to: Bridged" instead of "Attached to: NAT" in your VM's network adapter settings. That way your VMs appear to be plugged in directly to your LAN instead of through VirtualBox's (probably ipv4-only) NAT.

You do get a link-local IPv6 address automatically when IPv6 is enabled, no DHCP required.

Have you run `netsh interface ipv6 install` from the command line yet? See http://pugio.net/2007/07/howto-enable-ipv6-the-teredo-w.html

Comment: The pugio.net link is broken.

Comment: Archive.org has a version of the link: https://web.archive.org/web/20080517034906/http://pugio.net/2007/07/howto-enable-ipv6-the-teredo-w.html