# arch install network configuration: dhcpcd no ipv6 routers available

Tags: networking, dns, arch-linux, ipv6

I am new to arch and networking. After reading the doc and many posts, I am still unable to solve my problem.

I am running arch on virtualbox. The host machine uses a wireless connection. I installed arch, and followed the installation guide to set up my hostname and hostname resolution. But the network didn't work without install image. So I installed `dhcpcd` and enabled it. Now I am able to ping `8.8.8.8` and get response. But I am still unable to ping a domain name. And I get `no ipv6 routers available` message from `dhcpcd`.

I think this is related to DNS resolution. My `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty besides some comments. If I manually add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504963/how-to-solve-a-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-error/504975), the problem is solved. But my understanding is that I should not need to manually set the `resolv.conf` file, it should be handled by `hdcpcd`.

---

I think the problem is DNS resolution as detailed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Domain_name_resolution). I started the `dhcpcd` and `systemd-resolved`, now I am able to ping a domain name although the `dhcpcd` client still has the same error msg. `nslookup` and `host` cannot connect to server either.

Also, I have not set up clipboard so I only have screenshots. Any hints are helpful!
[image]

My host is a mbp with wireless connection, here is output of `ifconfig`

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
EHC29: flags=0<> mtu 0
EHC26: flags=0<> mtu 0
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether 10:dd:b1:a9:eb:c0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 4c:8d:79:e8:8e:d0
    inet6 fe80::1423:696d:a3f1:3d11%en1 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x8
    inet 192.168.0.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:8d:79:e8:8e:d0
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 52:8c:a3:f0:33:f7
    inet6 fe80::508c:a3ff:fef0:33f7%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether d2:00:18:1f:c2:40
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 10:dd:b1:ff:fe:81:fc:24
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether d2:00:18:1f:c2:40
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::461a:1df6:901b:70f5%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xe
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

This is the network setting of the VM. It's in default settings.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful to get a bit more context here, especially regarding the host OS config and your overall network. Also, it's worth noting that you may technically not necessarily need DHCP to configure IPv6 since that can also be achieved stateless.

Comment: Also, did you consider [this?](https://superuser.com/questions/76970/using-ipv6-with-virtualbox). In general I think this question needs a bit more info w.r.t. what you tried so far.

Comment: @jvda Thanks! so it seems this is a router connection problem? when I install the system I did not config wireless connection so I assumed the vm is somehow using the host machine's connection somehow. But it seems that is not the case? I need to configure the wireless connection here?

Comment: Not necessarily, and I can't know for sure without knowing more about your network (e.g. does your network even support IPv6?). But it is a common theme when using virtualbox that the network configuration of virtualbox (not the upstream router) is not configured in bridge mode. Can you post the virtualbox network config and the network config of the host OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both stateless (e.g. routing advertisements) and stateful (e.g. dhcp-v6) configuration mechanisms will only affect the guest OS if you switch from "Attached to: NAT" to "Bridge" networking.

If you use NAT (as you do now) both networks (the one used by host and by guest) are isolated. Only outbound traffic from the VM is NATed, therefore DHCP offers from your router are not reaching the VM.

Also, the IPv6 configuration of the interfaces on the host OS only show link-local addresses which may indicate that your network does not provide internet-access using IPv6.

To get around the DNS issue, you can either set the VM network to bridge mode as shown above, manually configure a reachable DNS server in `resolv.conf` (e.g. specifying your router or a public DNS) or enable [DNS proxying](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy).